# How to use cut and paste together in one go

Tags: unix, paste, cut

I am trying to use cut and paste in the same command line but somehow it does not work. 
I have two files, fileA and fileB.

```
fileA
a b
c d


fileB
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

I would like to cut the second and third column of fileB. I do this by the following command.

```
cut -f 2-3 fileB
```

Then in front of this, I would like to paste columns from fileA

```
paste fileA | cut -f 2-3 fileB > myNewFile
```

So myNewFile will look like

```
a b 2 3
c d 6 7
```

I can do this in two lines.

```
cut -f 2-3 fileB > part1
paste fileA part1 > myNewFile
```

But instead, i would like to do this in one go. Something similar to

```
paste fileA | cut -f 2-3 fileB > myNewFile
```

which does not work. It only prints the cut commands and do not do anything about the paste. How can i make this work in one command?

Thanks.

Comment: consider editing your question to include sample data, and required output from that sample. As it is, your question has too many 'what if's . Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

```
paste fileA <(cut -f 2-3 fileB) > myNewFile
```

Solution 2:

```
paste fileA fileB | cut -f1-2,4-5
```

Comment: Given `echo -e "a b\nc d" > fileA ; echo -e "1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8" > fileB`, specifying delimiters works better:  `paste -d ' ' file[AB] | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,4,5`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you probably want the `join` or `paste` commands.

An example using `paste` to join ALL columns, then some column manipulation commands to filter the desired columns, taken from http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=16618 is shown below:

```
$ cat foo
x1 y1
a1 b1
c1 d1
e1 f1

$ cat goo
x2 y2
a2 b2
c2 d2
e2 f2

$ paste foo goo
x1 y1   x2 y2
a1 b1   a2 b2
c1 d1   c2 d2
e1 f1   e2 f2

$ paste foo goo | column -t
x1  y1  x2  y2
a1  b1  a2  b2
c1  d1  c2  d2
e1  f1  e2  f2

$ paste foo goo | column -t | colrm 9 12
x1  y1  y2
a1  b1  b2
c1  d1  d2
e1  f1  f2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 paste fileA fileB | column -t | awk -F' ' '{print $1" "$2" "$4" "$5}'
```

or this

```
 paste fileA fileB | column -s' ' -t | sed 's/ \+ /\t/g' | sed 's/\t/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f1-2,4-5
```